# How do I make my java program use my custom JRE when executed by double-clicking, rather than the default JDK installed?

Tags: java, jar, exe

As you probably know, since JDK 9, JRE no longer exists. So you need to create your own custom JRE with jlink. Well, so did I. And then I converted the jar to exe using launch4j. However, when I double-click it, it uses the JDK located at `C:\Program File\Java\jdk-16.0.1` rather than the JRE I created. How do I make the exe use my JRE instead of the default JDK?

Thanks! Regards,

Fida

Comment: set path JAVA_HOME with your jre.

Comment: Like I mentioned in your previous question, why not just embed the JRE with your application?

Comment: How to embed the JRE with my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your jre used by applications then you have to set the path in your OS. But this will make all application to use your jre.

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\somepath\yourjre
```

You also have to update path variable with bin folder.

```
PATH = C:\somepath\yourjre\bin
```

Comment: I will try this. But is there any way to add/remove paths using cmd? How do I edit the JAVA_HOME in windows? I cannot find it in my environmental variables manager.

Comment: yes, you can set path in cmd also like set PATH="" or set JAVA_HOME=""

Comment: This time, I tested my app on a system without any java installed. I added `JAVA_HOME 
 = path to custom JRE` in both system variables and user variables. I also appended the JRE directory to the `path` variable. But still, when I double click on it, it says "Please install java first." That means it still cannot detect my JRE even after I edited the environmental variables. Now I think the only way left is to embed the JRE with my application or install the full JDK to have my clients run it. I might try the amazon JREs as well.

Comment: did you set the path correctly to your jre? After setting path try to run the jre commands i.e java and see what it is giving.

Comment: Yes, Pirate. I executed the `java -version` command without prepending the JRE directory to it. And it printed out the version information of my custom runtime, which is 16.0.1 in this case. I also had no java installed previously on that system, so the output surely came from my custom JRE. But double-clicking still doesn't work.

Comment: Here is the link to my environment variables screenshot: [link](https://i.imgur.com/feSknpq.png)

Comment: Path settings are not correct. You have to set without bin in **JAVA_HOME** and with /bin in **Path**

Comment: As you suggested, I have removed `\bin` from the `JAVA_HOME` variable. Now it looks like this: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/E7lhxIo.png). And then I restarted the PC, and tried again. But still no luck. There is one thing I didn't mention, that the system is windows 7.

Comment: Then you have to try some other way.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Perhaps the tips in the discussion will work for some other guy. For now, I'll try embedding the JRE into my java application.